# Factors and multiples

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Four traffic lights along a street turn red at regular intervals of 1 minute,1 minute 10 seconds,1 minute 18 seconds and 1 minute 31 seconds respectively.Occasionally all four traffic lights will turn red simultaneously.If all traffic lights turned red simultaneously at 0830,find the next time it occurs again.
    1 min=60 secs
    1 min 10 secs=70 secs
    1 min 18 secs=78 secs
    1 min 31 secs=91 secs

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please note that this is not a HW site. Please identify what you don't understand and/or share some of your own thoughts.

Answer (score 5):

You are just asking the least common multiple of the set
$$
\{60,70,78,91\}\,\,\text{(seconds.)}
$$